# Why is my <HR> tag not spanning the whole page?

Tags: html, css

for some reason, my `<HR>` tag isn't going across the page like the rest are:

http://gyazo.com/fad8cfaf31f3f1f585d0132e33d18c8f

I've figured out it was the side bar on the right but I can't find the exact problem.

My CSS for HR:

```
hr {
  position:relative;
  margin: 20px 0;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #666;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
```

CSS for sidebar:

```
.sidebar {
  position:relative;
  float:right;
  top:180px;
  left:290px;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Do you have any idea on what the problem might be?

HTML CODE/PHP:

```
<?php 
//--- Authenticate code begins here ---
session_start();
//checks if the login session is true

if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
header("location:index.php");
}
$username = $_SESSION['username'];

// --- Authenticate code ends here ---


 include ('header.php'); 



        ?>




    <div class="blog-wrap">


        <section class="blog-content">



            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style1.css">

            <form action="search.php" class="searchbar1" method="GET">
        <input type="text" name="query" />
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-search" value="Search" />
    </form>



<div style="float:right">  <a class="btn btn-danger logout" href="logout.php" > Logout</a> </div>

<div id="menu">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="home.php" target="_self" >Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="session1.php" target="_self" >Sessions</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="session1.php" target="_self" >Session 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="session2.php" target="_self" >Session 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="session3.php" target="_self" >Session 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="session4.php" target="_self" >Session 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="session5.php" target="_self" >Session 5</a></li>
                <li><a href="session6.php" target="_self" >Session 6</a></li>
                <li><a href="session7.php" target="_self" >Session 7</a></li>
                <li><a href="session8.php" target="_self" >Session 8</a></li>
                <li><a href="session9.php" target="_self" >Session 9</a></li>
                <li><a href="session10.php" target="_self" >Session 10</a></li>
                <li><a href="session11.php" target="_self" >Session 11</a></li>
                <li><a href="session12.php" target="_self" >Session 12</a></li>
                <li><a href="session13.php" target="_self" >Session 13</a></li>
                <li><a href="session14.php" target="_self" >Session 14</a></li>



            </ul>
            <li><a href="blog.php" target="_self" >Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="shop.php" target="_self" >Shop</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="sidebar">
<?php 
                include "blogsidebar.php";
            ?>
            </div>

            <section class="blog-inner">
                <div class="blog-posts">
                    <?php 
                        $sql = "SELECT blog.*, users.*, category.*, COUNT(comment.blogID) AS commentcount 
                        FROM blog INNER JOIN users ON blog.authorID = users.userID INNER JOIN category ON 
                        blog.catID = category.catID LEFT JOIN comment ON blog.blogID = comment.blogID GROUP BY 
                        blog.blogID, comment.blogID ORDER BY dateposted DESC LIMIT 0,3"; //display the last 3 blog entries and count the number of comments for each blog entry 

                        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error($connection)); //run the query 

                        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
                        { 

                        echo "<article class='blog-post one'>";
                        echo "<aside class='blog-text-prev'>";
                        echo "<div class='text-content'>";
                        echo "<h1><hr>" . $row['blogTitle'] . "</h1>";
                        echo "<h1>" . $row['categoryImage'] .  "  " . $row['fullname'] . "  ". $row['category'] ."  " . date("F jS",strtotime($row['dateTime'])) . " </h1>";
                        echo "<div class='clear'></div>";
                        echo "<p>" . (substr(($row['blogContent']),0,304)) . " <i><b><a href='blog-post.php?blogID=" .$row['blogID']. "'>Read More...</a></i></b></p>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "</aside>";
                        echo "</article>";
                        }
                    ?>

                </div>

            </section>
        </section>
    </div>
</section>
<!-- end login -->
<?php 
    include "footer.php";
?>
```

Comment: need the html of the area in question and a little more css.

Comment: @Brian I've added my HTML above

Comment: If you could isolate the problem in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that would be of great help. Then we don't have to wade through all kinds of code that isn't relevant.

Comment: how the output will be?

Comment: @SanderKoedood This is basically where the <HR> is echo "<h1><hr>" . $row['blogTitle'] . "</h1>";

Comment: please provide the same problem in a fiddle or show the code live somewhere.

Comment: You forgot to close `</li>`. In the line before the `<li><a href="blog.php" target="_self" >Blog</a></li>`, you have `</ul>`. Should be `</ul></li>` instead.

Comment: @JoseRuiSantos Didn't work :(

Comment: Even if you have some `typo` (missing `</li>`, inverted order with `</li> & </b> tags`) I presume it's impossible to tell with the code you provide. Please include the file `../css/style1.css`. And if you can, update this simplified jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gmolop/u7pk1hpd/

Comment: @Samantha, did either solution below work?

Comment: @Brian No unfortunately it did not :(

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the HTML/PHP you provided and this piece

`echo "<h1><hr>" . $row['blogTitle'] . "</h1>";`

I would assume that the `<hr>` is inheriting the width of the parent `<h1>` and granted the one you're having a problem with has a shorter title then the others, then that's probably it.

Either need to move the `<hr>` outside, and after the `<h1>` or set the blogtitle `<h1>` to `width: 100%;`